# Toggle between chart and table in panel

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datatables

I have a Highchart that renders properly into a bootstrap panel.

The Highchart code

```
$(function ()  {
var chart1;
$.get('graphdata/a000.txt?x='+microtime(), function(json){
obj = eval('({'+json+'})');
var $container = $('#container');
$(document).ready(function() {
chart = new  Highcharts.Chart(obj)
});
});
});
```

The panel code

```
<div id="container" class="panel-body">
```

I want to be able to toggle between the chart and a table (renders well separately in a separate panel) into the **same** panel through some button or switch

```
function myTable() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: mydata
    });
};

                          <table id="table" data-height="460"   class="panel-body">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
                                    <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
                                    <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
                                </tr>
                             </thead>
                         </table>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts.chart method remove all elements from the container. You should create separete container element for the chart and table and toggle their visibility in a function. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aj6ckzs2/

```
var chart = createChart(),
    table = $("#table"),
    chartContainer = $("#chartContainer");

table.bootstrapTable({
    data: myData
});

$("#toggle").on('click', function() {
    chartContainer.toggle();
    table.toggle();
});
```

If you still need to add the table directly to the same container as the chart, you will have to use chart.destroy method and add table to the container element, for example in this way:

```
function createChart() {
    return Highcharts.chart('container', {
        series: [{
            data: [...]
        }]
    });
}

function createTable() {
    var newTable = $("#table").clone(),
        container = $("#container");

    container.append(newTable);
    newTable.show();
    newTable.bootstrapTable({
        data: myData
    });
}

var myData = [...];
var chart = createChart();

$("#toggle").on('click', function() {
    if (chart.series) {
        chart.destroy();
        createTable();
    } else {
        chart = createChart();
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vqpdoynt/

Comment: Looks exactly what I need! But how do I adapt the CreateChart function to relate to the JSON graphdata/a000.txt file as in my code?